# Change Image Orientation to Normal in C# using MagickImage

Tags: imagemagick, exif

I need to change orientation of images to normal or remove the Exif orientation of the images using MagickImage in C# if at all it exists.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used AutoOrient() inbuilt function of MagickImage and it rotated the image to its normal orientation